# Simultaneous PHP Database Query

Tags: php, mysql, database

Suppose I have a function which is used to increment a column called project_id by 1 in the database under certain circumstances. (Assume auto increment will not satisfy this use case, due to logic that has to be run before determining whether to increment).

When a user clicks "New Project", the function finds the current largest project_id in the database, does SOME OTHER STUFF, and adds a row by incrementing project_id by 1.

Is there a possibility that when multiple users connect, the time that the server takes to process SOME OTHER STUFF, causes multiple users to pick up the same project_id? If so, how would you go about avoiding this problem? Is it just a bad idea to increment in this way?

Here is an illustration. This example is based on Laravel, but the question applies generally.

```
function ReallyLongFunction () {
    //figure out what the current max project_id is and increment by 1
    $newProjectId = Project::max("project_id")+1;


    //Some other stuff that the server has to do. I am exaggerating here the length of time.
    //If another user triggers this function, will both users will have the same project id?
    sleep(2);

   //Insert new row into database
   $project = new TempProject;
   $project->project_id = $newProjectId;
   $project->save();
}
```

Comment: I'm not a database expert but I would say, yes this is bad practice. Why doesn't auto increment work if you are trying to exactly perform an auto increment in your code?

Comment: You could create a "draft" record in your database each time the user presses the "new project" button and just burn the new auto increment ID if they cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a bad idea to do in your own code what the sql server can do better internally.  `$newProjectId = Project::max("project_id")+1;` sounds very much like a substitute for auto_increment. However if your requirement is more complex than that, you need [locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)

> [LOW_PRIORITY] WRITE lock:
>
> The session that holds the lock can read and write the table.
>
> Only the session that holds the lock can access the table. No other
>   session can access it until the lock is released.
>
> Lock requests for the table by other sessions block while the WRITE
>   lock is held.
>
> The LOW_PRIORITY modifier affects lock scheduling if the WRITE lock
>   request must wait, as described later.
>
> If the LOCK TABLES statement must wait due to locks held by other
>   sessions on any of the tables, it blocks until all locks can be
>   acquired.

If lot of users are accessing the same page concurrently the response will start to slow down because the second request cannot be served until the first one has completed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies... you've confirmed my suspicion that it wasn't the best way to go about things..